# Cannot establish TCP connection outside of LAN

Tags: tcp, client-server, remote-server, netcat

I have been trying to create a TCP connection between a client program and a remote server.  I am able to form a connection between the two when they are running on the same machine, and any machines connected to my router.  However, I am unable to form a connection to any of my friends' computers when I give them the server or client programs, and I am unable to form a connection between my computer and my remote server.

In order to locate the bug, I have shut down the firewalls of both my computer and my server, stopped using my own code and resorted to Netcat.  However, the situation remains identical:  I can form a server and connect to it with local machines, but cannot form any remote connections.

These are the commands I have been using with Netcat:

> nc -vv XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 1234
>
> nc -l -vv -p 1234

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there NATs involved? If so, have you set up port forwards on the NAT boxes?

Comment: Apparently my router has an NAT option that is enabled.  I can't say that I'm familiar with NAT though.  Should I just create a TCP rule to with Port Start, Port End, and Port Map all set to 1234, for this example?

Comment: yes, with the local (behind NAT) address of the computer where the server is listening.

Comment: I'm currently using AWS for my remote server, and am connecting to it with Remote Desktop, and am trying to connect to it with my desktop, which is connected to the internet by a router.  I added a TCP rule for AWS that consists of Port 1234 with a source of 0.0.0.0/0, and I added a rule to my router that sets Port Start, Port End, and Port Map to 1234.  I'm probably doing something wrong, because I am still unable to form a netcat connection hosted by either of them.